# How to create autodoc with sphinx on a pytest marked class?

Tags: python, pytest, python-sphinx, autodoc

Having such class marked with `pytest.mark.parametrize`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('app_lang', MobileAppLanguageMark.all(), scope='session')
class MobileBaseCase(BaseCase):
    def foo(self, a, b):
        """
        assadasdasda
        """
    return a,b
```

I'm trying to use sphinx autodoc to generate the docs.
This is `mobile_base_case.rst` file:

```
MobileBaseCase
=========================

.. autoclass:: plugin.lib.mobile.common.mobile_base_case.MobileBaseCase
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

The resulting html file after `make html` has only
[image]

I've also tried using

```
.. automethod:: foo(self, a, b)
.. automethod:: plugin.lib.mobile.common.mobile_base_case.MobileBaseCase.foo(self, a, b)
```

but with no luck.

Is there a way to make autodoc ignore the mark and generate docs for `MobileBaseCase` class?

Comment: You can make sphinx unwrap all ``pytest.mark.…`` instances, but the easiest approach would be just not to wrap it in the first place. At least in the example, the parametrization seems out of place. What *do* you document a class that is parametrized for unittesting with incompatible arguments?

Comment: The problem is that it has to be wrapped. In my framework this class has some generic methods for all test cases. Parametrizing is used to define the app language. Making sphinx unwrap it is more suitable solution here